# android imageview's position on map

Tags: android, google-maps

I used an ImageView to place a marker on top of map so that it would be immovable when the map moves.How do I place ImageView in the center of the map(equator) when it opens. How do I get the latitude and longitude of the ImageView's position on the map. I searched on google but did not get the code.Please help me....

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jobinsabu.markeranimator.MainActivity">
    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map1"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"> </fragment>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Map Animator"
        android:id="@+id/map_label"
        android:background="#70ffffff"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@drawable/marker"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    ImageView marker;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        marker=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.marker);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment=(SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);               
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);}
     @Override
     public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googlemap=googleMap;
        googlemap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googlemap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        googlemap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        }}
```

Comment: select answer if worked...!!

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    ImageView marker;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        marker=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.marker);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment=(SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);               
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);}
     @Override
     public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googlemap=googleMap;
        googlemap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googlemap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        googlemap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(lat_lng_of_equator)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ImageView_of_marker)));
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        }
     }
```

Comment: I have tried using marker, but I want the marker to be immovable when the camera position of the map is changed.Just like Uber

Comment: Yes, my answer is same, the marker will be immovable.

Comment: When I used ImageView instead of marker,it worked fine,but how to place it at center

Comment: what do u mean by center? User's current location or what?

Comment: Since equator is the center I want the ImageView to placed on it

Comment: get the latitude and longitude of equator and place on my marker method.

Comment: I did not get the desired effect.When I move the screen multiple markers are created.

Comment: I used cameraposition.target () to get center of the map and I removed the previous position of marker everytime the camera position is changed, but it did not give me the uber like effect

Comment: http://rajeshvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2015/08/uber-like-setting-location-by-dragging.html this might help

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own marker to googleMap

```
@Override
     public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googlemap=googleMap;
        googlemap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googlemap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        googlemap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
        Marker myMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(yourLocation)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));
        googleMap.addMarker(myMarker);
        }}
```

Comment: But the marker should be always visible to the user when the user moves the map

Comment: Marker is respective to particular lat,lng position when map moves its position changed, so them marker is not visible always. Until when you back to the previous location the marker is not visible